# Replace text across multiple files in a directory with sed

Tags: regex, unix, sed

I need to hide the IP addresses in the log files for security reasons. The IP addresses are of version 4 and 6. How do I hide the addresses in a way that,
 IPv4 example `123.4.32.16` is replaced by `x.x.x.x` and 
IPv6 example `232e:23o5:te43:5423:5433:0000:ef09:23ff` is replaced by `x:x:x:x:x:x:x:x`? 
Is it possible to do this using a single `sed` command?

Comment: Are all your IPv6 addresses in expanded form? If no, it's going to be a challenge... (and you want to use `sed`, `grep` only does regex matching)

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, the IPv6 addresses are in expanded form. The article here says that we can use grep for such situations: http://vasir.net/blog/ubuntu/replace_string_in_multiple_files/

Comment: You will see, however, that `grep` is piped to `sed` ;)

Comment: check here:http://theunixshell.blogspot.in/2012/12/find-and-replace-string-in-all-files.html

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use **find** and **sed** for this.

Let's assume your logs have the extension ".log":

```
find /path/to/logs -type f -name '*.log' -exec       \
sed -i -e 's,[0-9]\+\(\.[0-9]\+\)\{3\},x.x.x.x,g'    \
-e 's,[0-9a-f]\+\(:[0-9a-f]\+\)\{7\},x:x:x:x:x:x:x:x,gi' {} \;
```

How does this work?

1. First, we ask **find** to recursively locate files with the **.log** extension starting from **/path/to/logs**. **-type f** tells find we wan't to find regular files.
2. For each file, it will execute **sed**. The **-i** argument tells sed you want to edit the file in place. (Check out http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html)

Comment: @brain: You said "-type f tells find we wan't to find regular files", do you mean regular text files?

Answer (score 0):

One solution using `find` and `perl`:

```
find /the/directory -type f -exec perl -pi -e '
    s/\b\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3}\b/x.x.x.x/g;
    s/\b[a-f\d]{1,4}(:[a-f\d]{1,4}){7}\b/x:x:x:x:x:x:x:x/gi' {} \;
```

(type on one line)

Answer (score 0):

Well, first you should probably just fix whatever is doing the logging to log the way you want to.

Now if you need to go back and modify historical files, you might consider using `sed`

```
sed -e 's/\b(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\b/x.x.x.x/' /path/to/file
sed -e 's/\b([:xdigit:]{4}:){7}[:xdigit:]{4}\b/x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x/' /path/to_file
```

Comment: Also, IPv6 is hexadecimal (and `sed` has `/i`).

Comment: Actually I meant to say that it has the `/i` regex modifier (what is `\i`?)

Comment: shows how often I search for hex values... I'll just go with `[:xdigit:]`

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

`find . -name "*.log" -exec grep -izl PATTERN {} \; | xargs perl -i.orig -e -n 's/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/g'`

You'd want to insert your PATTERN(s) and replace *.log with something else depending on the name of your log files.

The -i.orig backs up the files being replaced with an extension of .orig.

I found that this was relatively faster than other things I tried.  find/grep combo to indentify candidates, then perl to do the work.